# API Gateway mapping template is not sending JWT auth claims to Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-lambda-integration

I am having trouble sending specific JWT authorization claims information derived from the Authorization header of a request to an API Gateway REST API endpoint (with non-proxy Lambda integration). The endpoint is secured with a Cognito User Pool Authorizer with Login with Amazon as the identity provider. From the Cloudwatch execution logs of API Gateway, I can see the JWT authorizer claims:

```
(***) Cognito User Pool Authorizer claims from JWT: {
    at_hash=***,
    sub=***,
    cognito:groups=us-east-1_***_LoginWithAmazon,
    email_verified=false,
    iss=https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_***,
    cognito:username=loginwithamazon_amzn1.account.***,
    nonce=***,
    origin_jti=***,
    aud=***,
    identities={
        "dateCreated":"***",
        "userId":"amzn1.account.***",
        "providerName":"LoginWithAmazon",
        "providerType":"LoginWithAmazon",
        "issuer":null,
        "primary":"true"
    },
    token_use=id,
    auth_time=***,
    name=***,
    exp=*** UTC 2022,
    iat=*** UTC 2022,
    jti=***,
    email=***
}

(***) Method request path: {}
(***) Method request query string: {}
(***) Method request headers: {Authorization=******[TRUNCATED]
(***) Method request body before transformations: 
(***) Endpoint request URI: https://lambda.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:***:function:***/invocations
(***) Endpoint request headers: {x-amzn-lambda-integration-tag=***, Authorization=***, X-Amz-Date=***, x-amzn-apigateway-api-id=***, X-Amz-Source-Arn=arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:***:***/***/GET/myapi, Accept=application/json, User-Agent=AmazonAPIGateway_***, X-Amz-Security-Token=*** [TRUNCATED]
(***) Method request body after transformations:
```

I defined the following mapping template to compose a Lambda function event containing the API request body, parameters, headers, and a context that holds specific pieces of information from the JWT claims object:

```
##  See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html
##  This template will pass through all parameters including path, querystring, header, stage variables, and context through to the integration endpoint via the body/payload
#set($allParams = $input.params())
{
"body-json" : $input.json('$'),
"params" : {
#foreach($type in $allParams.keySet())
    #set($params = $allParams.get($type))
"$type" : {
    #foreach($paramName in $params.keySet())
    "$paramName" : "$util.escapeJavaScript($params.get($paramName))"
        #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
    #end
}
    #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
#end
},
"stage-variables" : {
#foreach($key in $stageVariables.keySet())
"$key" : "$util.escapeJavaScript($stageVariables.get($key))"
    #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
#end
},
"context" : {
    "account-id" : "$context.identity.accountId",
    "api-id" : "$context.apiId",
    "caller" : "$context.identity.caller",
    "http-method" : "$context.httpMethod",
    "request-id" : "$context.requestId",
    "resource-id" : "$context.resourceId",
    "resource-path" : "$context.resourcePath",
    "userId": "$context.authorizer.claims.identities.userId",
    "name": "$context.authorizer.claims.name",
    "email": "$context.authorizer.claims.email",
    "email_verified": "$context.authorizer.claims.email_verified"
    }
}
```

When I log a JSON dump of the event object to Cloudwatch, I see an empty JSON object `{}`. Is my mapping template the problem, or is my API Gateway configuration causing this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I am supposed to deploy the API every time I make a change to the VTL mapping template! Just hitting the [Save] button after modifying the template does not allow the change to take effect. AWS documentation should be updated, since it is not apparent when the API should be re-deployed.

Also, since the value of the `identities` key in the JWT authorizer claims is a String, I needed to make a slight modification to the above mapping template on the `userId` property.

```
"userId": "$util.parseJson($context.authorizer.claims.identities).userId",
```